# How to provide custom capabilities on the selenium server?

Tags: java, selenium, remotewebdriver, desiredcapabilities

I know that some selenium capabilities can be obtained with a method, one of them like this :

`driver.getCapabilities().getBrowserName();`

It returns the value of the browser name.

But if it refers to an available method, if I don't misunderstand it, this seems to be related to custom capabilities, like this I mean :

`driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("something ?");`

**Returns:** The value, or null if not set.

[image: get capabilities]

So, I've tried to make a simple code to get the value I mean.

```
    private RemoteWebDriver driver;
    private URL url;
    private DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        url = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
        dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, BrowserType.CHROME);
        //this is custom capability i mean
        dc.setCapability("testName", "Login");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, dc);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        some code.....
    }
    
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("Browser Name : "+ driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("browserName"));
        System.out.println("Test Name : "+ driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("testName"));
        driver.quit();
    }
```

With `json`, server log say :

```
Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "testName": "Login"
}
```

[image: server log]

But i get a `null` value.

How to the right setup ? How do you make our server provide the capabilities `testName` I mean? and can be obtained with `driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("testName");`

**Current result** `Browser Name : chrome` `Test Name : null`

**Expected result** `Browser Name : chrome` `Test Name : Login`

Thanks advance

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#capabilities this may help understanding the capabilities . Remote end will not return values if its not supported.

Comment: @RahulL yes correct, if i use `.getCapability("browserName")` `platformName` etc, it will return a value, but it still the default available in selenium. I've used a paid testing platform (platform based on selenium and appium) and for the purposes of the report name I can only setup by adding the `dc.setCapability("testName"," Login ")` method, and I can get the value of `testName` using the method `.getCapability ("testName")`, even I can also get the value of the report url using the `.getCapability ("urlReport")` method. So I assume that the name of the capability can be custom as needed.

Comment: But in the fact it's not simple as my imagine

Comment: Sauce lab or Browser stack have their own implementations of remote servers. They don't use selenium remote server as it is . So there server recognize capabilities defined by them. Example https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid implemented in go language

Comment: So, you mean, the capabilities that I mean are made separate from the Selenium framework ?

Comment: Answer is Yes.As per W3C protocol -'Remote ends may also introduce extension capabilities that are extra capabilities used to provide configuration or fulfill other vendor-specific needs' Capability dc.setCapability("testName", "Login") It will be sent in Json but it will be ignored by remote server .When you request it back it will  not send anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197515/discussion-between-frian-and-rahul-l).

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the *WebDriver Capabilities* e.g. `Browser Name`, `Browser Version`, `Platform Name`, etc using either of the following solutions:

- Using direct APIs:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    System.out.println("Class Name is : "+((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getClass().toString());
    System.out.println("Browser Name is : "+((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName().toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("Browser Version is : "+((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getVersion().toString());
    System.out.println("Platform Name is : "+((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getPlatform().toString());
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    Class Name is : class org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities
    Browser Name is : firefox
    Browser Version is : 67.0
    Platform Name is : WINDOWS
    ```
- Using `getCapability()`:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
    System.out.println("acceptInsecureCerts value is: "+cap.getCapability("acceptInsecureCerts"));
    System.out.println("Browser Name is : "+cap.getBrowserName());
    System.out.println("Browser version is : "+cap.getVersion());           
    System.out.println("Platform is : "+cap.getPlatform().toString());
    System.out.println("javascriptEnabled value is: "+cap.getCapability("javascriptEnabled"));
    System.out.println("moz:accessibilityChecks value is: "+cap.getCapability("moz:accessibilityChecks"));
    System.out.println("moz:buildID value is: "+cap.getCapability("moz:buildID"));
    System.out.println("geckodriverVersion value is: "+cap.getCapability("geckodriverVersion"));
    System.out.println("Headless Mozilla value is: "+((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getCapability("moz:headless"));
    System.out.println("moz:headless value is: "+cap.getCapability("moz:headless"));
    System.out.println("Mozilla Profile value is : "+ ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getCapability("moz:profile"));
    System.out.println("moz:processID value is : "+cap.getCapability("moz:processID"));
    System.out.println("moz:profile value is : "+cap.getCapability("moz:profile"));
    System.out.println("moz:shutdownTimeout value is : "+cap.getCapability("moz:shutdownTimeout"));
    System.out.println("moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin value is : "+cap.getCapability("moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin"));
    System.out.println("moz:webdriverClick value is : "+cap.getCapability("moz:webdriverClick"));
    System.out.println("pageLoadStrategy value is : "+cap.getCapability("pageLoadStrategy"));
    System.out.println("Platform is : "+cap.getPlatform().toString());
    System.out.println("platformName value is : "+cap.getCapability("platformName"));
    System.out.println("platformVersion value is : "+cap.getCapability("platformVersion"));
    System.out.println("rotatable value is : "+cap.getCapability("rotatable"));
    System.out.println("setWindowRect value is : "+cap.getCapability("setWindowRect"));
    System.out.println("strictFileInteractability value is : "+cap.getCapability("strictFileInteractability"));
    System.out.println("timeouts values are : "+cap.getCapability("timeouts"));
    System.out.println("unhandledPromptBehavior value is : "+cap.getCapability("unhandledPromptBehavior"));
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    acceptInsecureCerts value is: true
    Browser Name is : firefox
    Browser version is : 67.0
    Platform is : WINDOWS
    javascriptEnabled value is: true
    moz:accessibilityChecks value is: false
    moz:buildID value is: 20190516215225
    geckodriverVersion value is: null
    Headless Mozilla value is: false
    moz:headless value is: false
    Mozilla Profile value is : C:\Users\Debanjan.B\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.7HI7QUtzF1YP
    moz:processID value is : 7308
    moz:profile value is : C:\Users\Debanjan.B\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.7HI7QUtzF1YP
    moz:shutdownTimeout value is : 60000
    moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin value is : false
    moz:webdriverClick value is : true
    pageLoadStrategy value is : normal
    Platform is : WINDOWS
    platformName value is : WINDOWS
    platformVersion value is : 6.2
    rotatable value is : false
    setWindowRect value is : true
    strictFileInteractability value is : false
    timeouts values are : {implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}
    unhandledPromptBehavior value is : dismiss and notify
    ```

> You can find the list of the supported capabilities in the [Capabilities](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#capabilities) section within the *WebDriver
>   W3C Recommendation*

Comment: Thanks. But `browserName` `browserVersion` `platformName` is default capability from selenium, i need custom `string name` to set capability and get value it.

Comment: @Frian Check out the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: i've updated my question with more explanation, maybe you have any idea.

Comment: @Frian _testName_ is not a standard capability. You can't send it to _RemoteWebDriver_.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is how to add a custom capability to your Grid configuration.  This is possible, but requires several steps.

First, you need to build a capability matcher.  The matcher will be its own project, importing the Selenium-Server and Selenium-Java libraries as dependencies.  You'll need a single class that extends `org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher`, and overrides the `matches()` method with your own logic to determine whether or not a node possesses the desired capability.  When complete, you'll build this project and generate a jar file.

Second, you'll need to attach your new matcher to your Grid Hub.  I store my matcher jars in the same directory as my selenium-server-standalone jar, and I alter my normal launch command to accommodate the matcher.

```
java -cp <custom-matcher>-1.0.0.jar;selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher -role hub -hubConfig hubConfig.json
```

In my `hubConfig.json`, I had to add two lines to the JSON to wire in the matcher:

```
  "capabilityMatcher": "fully.qualified.path.to.Matcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
```

Third, you'll need to configure your nodes to accept the new capability.  If you're using JSON to also configure your nodes, it's just as simple as adding a new line for your capability:

```
"capabilityName": "foo"
```

That's pretty much it.  It's also worth noting that `DesiredCapabilities` does have a capability called `applicationName`, which is left as a user-definable value.  Depending on your specific use case, you might be able to leverage this capability in place of adding something new.

I found a [sample repo](https://github.com/diemol/custom-capability-matcher) on Github a while back when I was learning this process myself.  It's a basic setup, but it illustrates the steps above pretty well.  It should give you a great starting point for your own implementation.

Comment: Let me check, i'll back to you.

Comment: sorry for late response, thank before for the suggest. I've complete the steps like your suggest, long enough in the first step :), but can you correct my job ? wrong or true with your review. Hub and node fine work, indicate by `10:29:44.122 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use`.

Comment: This is the value `custom-capability.jar` : `public class CustomCapability extends DefaultCapabilityMatcher {
 private final String testName = "testName";
 boolean allCapabilitiesAvailability = false;`

Comment: `@Override 
 public boolean matches(Map<String, Object> nodeCapability, Map<String, Object> requestedCapability){
  boolean defaultCapabilitiesAvailability = super.matches(nodeCapability, requestedCapability);
  if (! requestedCapability.containsKey(testName)){
   return defaultCapabilitiesAvailability;
  }else {
   boolean nodeOSAvailability = nodeCapability.get(testName).equals(requestedCapability.get(testName));
   allCapabilitiesAvailability = (defaultCapabilitiesAvailability && nodeOSAvailability);
   return allCapabilitiesAvailability;
  }
 }
}`

Comment: This is the value `hubConfig.json` : `{
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {},
  "capabilityMatcher": "com.matcher.CustomCapability",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "role": "hub",
  "debug": false,
  "browserTimeout": 0,
  "timeout": 1800
}`

Comment: So execute the hub with this command : `java -cp custom-capability.jar:selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 -role hub -hubConfig hubConfig.json`

Comment: This is the value `nodeConfig.json` : `{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "testName": "untitled"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "testName": "untitled"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444"`

Comment: So execute the node with this command : `java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver -cp custom-capability.jar:selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json`

Comment: My question is, the test script code like this question i've tried set `dc.setCapability("testName", "untitled");` it's fine work, but if i use this command : `driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("testName")` it's return `null`. Then i've tried set `dc.setCapability("testName", "login");`, it's getting error like this : `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, testName: login}`

Comment: Did the results of your suggestion really produce this ? if not, then where is my mistake ? Because the point of my question is how `testName` can be made like a parameter, it can be filled with any `string` value, and I can get the `testName` value with this : `driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("testName")`, thanks and please help me again for review :)

Comment: Just at a quick glance, I think the launch command for your nodes might need to be changed.  I'd start by dropping the `-Dwebdriver` args. There is also, apparently, a known issue right now with capability matchers, but workarounds exist.  Please see [this](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/3268#issuecomment-451397251) over at Github.

Comment: I will visit the link and investigate, btw with the correct result, is I can change the value `testName` capability with any string like I mean ? example : `dc.setCapability("testName", "login");`

Comment: `dc.setCapability()` isn't meant to assign a new value. The Matcher and the JSON configuration define a set of capabilities held by the Node (such as which browser, which OS, etc). In the case of custom capabilities (such as your `testName` option), you'll assign a value to each node in the JSON configuration. Then, when configuring your `DesiredCapabilities` instance to be passed to your `RemoteWebDriver`, you're telling DC which capabilities to seek out when choosing a Node on which to run the test.

Comment: By invoking `setCapability()`, you are telling DC which of the options to use that you've assigned to your various Nodes. In your example, `dc.setCapability("testName", "login")`, you're instructing DC to find a Node with the `"login"` value for the `"testName"` capability.