# What are the capabilities of the browser opened by selenium-webdriver?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am curious to know the capabilities of the Chrome browser opened through the code:

```
driver=webdriver.chromedriver()
```

Is it same as that of `incognito` mode or is there a different kind?

Comment: Why not try and see? Anyway, you can instantiate chrome with a bottomless pit of switches depending on what you're trying to accomplish. For example: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#incognito

Answer (score 1):

To extract the capabilities of the *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome Browser* you can use the `capabilities` property which returns a dictionary and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
  my_dict = driver.capabilities
  for key,val in my_dict.items():
      print (key, "=>", val)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  acceptInsecureCerts => False
  browserName => chrome
  browserVersion => 76.0.3809.100
  chrome => {'chromedriverVersion': '76.0.3809.68 (420c9498db8ce8fcd190a954d51297672c1515d5-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#864})', 'userDataDir': 'C:\\Users\\Debanjan.B\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir3888_683123771'}
  goog:chromeOptions => {'debuggerAddress': 'localhost:26050'}
  networkConnectionEnabled => False
  pageLoadStrategy => normal
  platformName => windows nt
  proxy => {}
  setWindowRect => True
  strictFileInteractability => False
  timeouts => {'implicit': 0, 'pageLoad': 300000, 'script': 30000}
  unhandledPromptBehavior => dismiss and notify
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to provide custom capabilities on the selenium server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57352924/how-to-provide-custom-capabilities-on-the-selenium-server/57356948#57356948)