# Kill Selenium Browser by PID Process [Java]

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pid

`Selenium` sometimes fails to close after calling `driver.quit()` when it gets stuck at "connection to server was reset" or when it simply "stops responding". When this occurs, it is impossible kill the process (browser) using `WebDriver` directly, the only way I can think of is by retrieving the `PID` of browser and destroying process via:

```
String cmd = "taskkill /F /PID " + pidOfBrowser;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

I'm aware of [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17088847) which suggests retrieving a list of processes currently running and filtering it down to Firefox browser. However, as someone pointed out in one of the comments this does not work if a user has many concurrent sessions running and only wishes to kill a select few.

Another solution suggested in the comment section of that thread is to get a list of PIDs from the browser before starting, and only close those that were not running before the test started (so any browser launched manually before tests began won't close)

However, this does not apply to my situation because I am launching many browsers at a time from my program (not manually) and only wish to close some of the browsers launched (the ones that are hanging and not responding to `WebDriver` anymore).

How can I get `PID` of a specific `Firefox WebDriver` session (ideally when it is created) so I can kill the process later if it hangs or gets 'stuck'?

Thanks!

Comment: how about this `from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
print(driver.service.process.pid)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752512/get-pid-of-browser-launched-by-selenium)  . when you close , make sure you bring the window in focus and use `driver.close()` as driver.quit()` will close all windows

Comment: We don't clean up mid run... we wait until the run is complete and then kill all processes (or kill all before a run starts). Why do you need to clean up mid run?

Comment: @JeffC I'm  launching browser after browser - as long as system detects there's sufficient memory, next browser is launched automatically so there is no delay between launches. If I have to wait until all browsers finish doing their work before launching the next set of browsers it will slow down system.. as each browser can take different amount of time to complete work. This is why I need to kill browser as soon as I detect it is 'stuck' so I could launch a replacement immediately..

Comment: @user1207289 that thread is in Python. I don't see how to do this with Java. If it's possible to get PID of Firefox session/brwoser in Java please post as solution and I will accept. Thanks!

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467793/how-can-i-get-chromedriver-process-pid-using-java

Answer (score 1):

You can kill the *Browser* instance initiated using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) retriving the *PID* from the [*capabilities*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57352924/how-to-provide-custom-capabilities-on-the-selenium-server/57356948#57356948) object and then invoking `getRuntime()` with `taskkill /PID` as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

  public class Kill_Firefox_PID {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
          System.out.println("moz:processID value is : "+cap.getCapability("moz:processID"));
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /PID "+cap.getCapability("moz:processID"));
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  moz:processID value is : 8492
  ```

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks. Will accept as final solution later today. Just one question: Is it possible to achieve this without casting to RemoteWebDriver? As I currently don't rely on RemoteWebDriver but I guess casting to RemoteWebDriver can't hurt..

Comment: @S.O.S Yes, it's possible through os level client calls but comparatively using [`getCapabilities()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getCapabilities--) things are much simpler.

Comment: @DebanjanB Is it possible to get the geckodriver process that is associated with driver instance using capabilities ?

Comment: @AlanCook Yes it's possible but that's a separate question and you may have to raise a new ticket.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 9+ version you can do like this. It is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProcessHandle.allProcesses()
            .forEach(process -> System.out.println(processDetails(process)));
}

private static String processDetails(ProcessHandle process) {
    return String.format("%8d %8s %10s %26s %-40s",
            process.pid(),
            text(process.parent().map(ProcessHandle::pid)),
            text(process.info().user()),
            text(process.info().startInstant()),
            text(process.info().commandLine()));
}

private static String text(Optional<?> optional) {
    return optional.map(Object::toString).orElse("-");
}
```

and then get `info` of the process like above. There is a `totalCpuDuration​()` method in [`ProcessHandle.Info`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.Info.html) class. use this to see which process is taking long and then act accordingly. There are other methods in that class that can be beneficial in your scenario.  Hope this helps.